# Manifest file secret storage cloud foundary

Tags: manifest, cicd, concourse

I want to keep secret in manifest file as dynamic variables under env: block

like below

env:
var: ${VALUE}

The VALUE i push from concourse pipeline like below

- params
  environment_variables:
  VALUE: test

But it is not working Anyone can help on this ?

i tried keeping manifest default value and override with params in pipeline but it did not work.
Directly put under params like below :

params:
VALUE: test

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).